# Javascript: Multiplying an input value with multiple table cell values and assign it to other table cells

Tags: javascript

I am trying to multiply an input value with multiple table cells and assign the results of each calculation to the table cell to the right of each cell except for the first row.
Here is my javascipt:

```
<script>
    function updateTable() {
        var x;
        var itemPrice = document.getElementById("inputPrice");
        var newPrice;
        for (i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
            x = document.getElementById("table1").rows[i].cells;
            newPrice = (parseInt(x[1].innerHTML)+1) * itemPrice;
            x[2].innerHTML = newPrice;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: itemPrice will be an HTML element - you can't multiply by an object - you need to convert that to a number like you do with the cell content

Comment: You need to use `itemPrice.value`.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to get the value from inputPrice.

```
 var itemPrice = document.getElementById("inputPrice").value;
```

You can see an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/24m13Luq/)

Comment: Ah, that's it! Thank you.